# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, twitter4j

please help me. I'm getting a null pointer exception error in my code. Here it is:

```
    File strfile = new File("15.json");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (strfile);

    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        Status statjson = DataObjectFactory.createStatus(json);
        String text = statjson.getText();

    if (text == null)
    {
        System.out.print("null");
    }
           else { System.out.print(text); }     }
```

it runs for the first few lines that have a "text" field but the moment it comes across a line without "text" it throws a null pointer exception instead of printing "null" on the console. Help please!

Comment: I see potentially two (maybe three) places where you could get an NPE.  Which line (specifically) are you getting it on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `==` operator to check Object references

```
if (text == null)
```

Comment: and what did the stacktrace reveal? can you post it for us?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if(text.equals(null))
```

to:

```
if(text == null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Pradeep. I've just done that and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace with exact line where you're getting exception?

Answer (score 0):

If 'text' is null, text.equals will throw a NPE. Use the == operator.